# How to let Timer skip through the task when last one haven't finished?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Here is the code snippet:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    int i = 0;
    int longTimeJobPoint = 2;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date());
        if(++i == longTimeJobPoint)    {
            try {
                System.out.println("sleeping time...");
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

};

//every 10 sec
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), 10000);
```

The result is as follows:

```
Sat Oct 19 10:44:59 CST 2013
Sat Oct 19 10:45:09 CST 2013
sleeping time...
Sat Oct 19 10:45:39 CST 2013  //piled task
Sat Oct 19 10:45:39 CST 2013  //piled task
Sat Oct 19 10:45:39 CST 2013
Sat Oct 19 10:45:49 CST 2013
```

As we can see, When `Thread.sleep()` delayed for 30 seconds, the scheduled timer **piles up** the tasks that should be invoked every 10 seconds. What I want is to **skip the tasks that have been delayed because of the last task has not finished yet.** And the output should be like this:

```
Sat Oct 19 10:44:59 CST 2013
Sat Oct 19 10:45:09 CST 2013
sleeping time...
Sat Oct 19 10:45:39 CST 2013
Sat Oct 19 10:45:49 CST 2013
```

Could anyone give me some help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [fixed-delay execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) instead, which starts the next task based on the previous task's completion time instead of its start time. If `Timer` doesn't support what you need, look at a more capable scheduling library like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).